# Change monaco editor context menu labels

Tags: javascript, angular

I use monaco-editor version 0.34.1 with angular 14.
I am trying to change context menu labels that exists by the original monaco initialize.
This is my configuration to my custom language:
`export function myMonacoLoad() {
monaco.languages.register({
id: 'planit'
});

```
// Brackets rules.
const config: monaco.languages.LanguageConfiguration = {

    // Allow square brackets to be part of a word if . is part of the word comletion not work.
    wordPattern: /(-?\d*\.\d\w*)|([^\#\(\)\'\"\,\.]+)/g,
    surroundingPairs: [{ open: '(', close: ')' }, { open: '"', close: '"' }],
    autoClosingPairs: [{ open: '(', close: ')' }, { open: '"', close: '"' }],
    brackets: [['(', ')']],
};
monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration('planit', config);
monaco.editor.defineTheme('planitTheme', {
    base: 'vs',
    inherit: true,
    rules: [
        { token: 'operator-type', foreground: '918100' },
        { token: 'property', foreground: '003060' },
        { token: 'calculation-constant', foreground: '238384' },
        { token: 'comment', foreground: '369C41' },
        { token: 'date', foreground: 'B04B04' },
        { token: 'text', foreground: 'B04B04' },
        { token: 'const', foreground: '0859a8' }
    ],
    colors: {
        'editor.foreground': '#000000'
    }
});
```

}`

then I add my custom actions like this:
`
const colorPickerActopn = {

```
  // An unique identifier of the contributed action.
  id: 'color-picker',

  // A label of the action that will be presented to the user.
  label: 'Color Picker',

  // A precondition for this action.
  precondition: null,

  // A rule to evaluate on top of the precondition in order to dispatch the keybindings.
  keybindingContext: null,

  contextMenuGroupId: '9_cutcopypaste',

  contextMenuOrder: 7,

  // Method that will be executed when the action is triggered.
  // @param editor The editor instance is passed in as a convenience.
  // Interface on monaco editor is ICodeEditor.
  run: this.monacoEditorService.colorPicker
};

this.editor.addAction(colorPickerActopn);

const commentAction = {
  // An unique identifier of the contributed action.
  id: 'comment',

  // A label of the action that will be presented to the user.
  label: 'Comment',

  // An optional array of keybindings for the action.
  keybindings: [
    monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.Slash,
  ],

  // A precondition for this action.
  precondition: null,

  // A rule to evaluate on top of the precondition in order to dispatch the keybindings.
  keybindingContext: null,

  contextMenuGroupId: '9_cutcopypaste',

  contextMenuOrder: 8,

  // Method that will be executed when the action is triggered.
  // @param editor The editor instance is passed in as a convenience.
  // Interface on monaco editor is ICodeEditor.
  run: this.monacoEditorService.commentRow
};
this.editor.addAction(commentAction);

const hatchAction = {
  // An unique identifier of the contributed action.
  id: 'hatch',

  // A label of the action that will be presented to the user.
  label: 'Hatch',

  // A precondition for this action.
  precondition: null,

  // A rule to evaluate on top of the precondition in order to dispatch the keybindings.
  keybindingContext: null,

  contextMenuGroupId: '9_cutcopypaste',

  contextMenuOrder: 6,

  // Method that will be executed when the action is triggered.
  // @param editor The editor instance is passed in as a convenience.
  // Interface on monaco editor is ICodeEditor.
  run: this.monacoEditorService.hatchPicker
};
this.editor.addAction(hatchAction);
```

`

That is the menu result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLjC1.png)

I also tried to use `import * as actions from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/actions/common/actions';`

but no actions inside.

How can I change the menu items that not I entered(Need change the labels)?